# How to configure a house ad on Android to trigger an in-app subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, subscriptions

I have an ad-supported app and a subscribe to "Remove Ads" feature. I would like to include my "own ads" (house ads) to promote and advertise the "Remove Ads" feature.

I understand that any Ad must "link" to something. In this particular case, I would like my ad directly pop up a Google Play store prompt inviting the user to pay for a subscription.

I have read about IAP house ads here: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6145807?hl=en

This seems to be exactly what I want, however they have a statement that says: "AdMob currently only supports managed in-app products; subscriptions are not currently supported."

(See the implementation guide: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6145824?hl=en&ref_topic=6145802)

Since my current system has a "Subscribe" to remove ads (that charges the user monthly), it appears that a House Ad won't do the trick. It is quite baffling why linking to a subscription would be disallowed?

I wanted to know if there is another way to achieve this? The other option that struck me is: Could I have a house ad that links to a "deep link within my *own* current app". The user can be then directed to a screen that provides more details on the subscription which THEN links to the "subscription" from Google play. That is, would an "intermediate" screen do the trick?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I am wondering if you found any solution for this since i am looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: As per my answer below. This is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently NOT possible to have a house-ad trigger an in-app subscription. It is only possible to trigger an in-app purchase that is **NOT** a subscription.

This is not only from the documentation (as I have referenced above), but a direct question to Google customer service. They indicate that in the **future** Google will enable house ads to link to in-app subscriptions. There appears to be no specific reason why this is the case right now, but more like an unimplemented feature.